# Generate PDF from Html using iTextSharp with css

Tags: pdf-generation

> I want to generate PDF From html with css file.
>
> I am not able to found why my MemoryStream is blanck after
>   XMLParser.Parse()
>
> I am using iTextShratp 5.5.6 virsion for this.

Here string html contains all html data.
Method 1 :

```
  Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20);
    MemoryStream PDFData = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, PDFData);
    document.Open();

    string html = PageContentLayout();

    // CSS
    var cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver();
    var cssFile = XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ClientFiles/assets/css/style1.css"), FileMode.Open));
    cssResolver.AddCss(cssFile);

    // HTML
    CssAppliers ca = new CssAppliersImpl();
    HtmlPipelineContext hpc = new HtmlPipelineContext(ca);
    hpc.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

    // PIPELINES
    PdfWriterPipeline pdf = new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer);
    HtmlPipeline htmlPipe = new HtmlPipeline(hpc, pdf);
    CssResolverPipeline css = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipe);

    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
    XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(html);
    MemoryStream msInput = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(html));
    p.Parse(sr);

    writer.CloseStream = false;
    document.Close();
```

Method 2 :

```
XMLWorkerHelper worker1 = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
worker1.ParseXHtml(writer, document, new StringReader(html));
```

Method 3 :

```
MemoryStream msInput = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(html));
    MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();

    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 20, 20, 20, 20);
    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, msOutput);

    doc.Open();

    CssFilesImpl cssFiles = new CssFilesImpl();
    cssFiles.Add(XMLWorkerHelper.GetCSS(new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ClientFiles/assets/css/style1.css"), FileMode.Open)));
    StyleAttrCSSResolver cssResolver = new StyleAttrCSSResolver(cssFiles);

    CssAppliers ca = new CssAppliersImpl();
    HtmlPipelineContext hpc = new HtmlPipelineContext(ca);
    hpc.SetAcceptUnknown(true).AutoBookmark(true).SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());
    HtmlPipeline htmlPipeline = new HtmlPipeline(hpc, new PdfWriterPipeline(doc, pdfWriter));
    IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, htmlPipeline);

    XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
    XMLParser xmlParse = new XMLParser(true, worker);
    xmlParse.Parse(msOutput);
```

---

If i use Method 2 then pdf is generate successfully but i am not able to find any way to add css in this method.

Comment: I'm having same issue, were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score -3):

Hi all please use winnovative html to pdf, Hiqpdf or EVO Html to pdf convert these are far better then iTextSharp and easy to implement but not free you need to buy licence for these.

Comment: This does not answer the question.